What workarounds exist for Visual Studio's broken Performance Profiler with .NET 8?
Problem
I have a .NET 8 C# application that I want to run under Visual Studio 2022's performance profiler and see a breakdown of CPU time alongside code (the bottom pane view in the "Call Tree" view of a CPU usage report; I don't know what name the VS team formally gives to this display). However, at present while I can see the top pane of the "Call Tree" view, the bottom pane displays only this error message:

Unable to find symbol file, change symbol file locations to specify correct search paths.

Additionally, in VS's "Output" pane with "Diagnostics Hub" selected, the following lines are shown:
Symbols failed to load for system.private.corelib.dll. Failed to find local symbol file System.Private.CoreLib.ni.pdb
Symbols failed to load for system.console.dll. Failed to find local symbol file System.Console.ni.pdb
Symbols failed to load for system.linq.dll. Failed to find local symbol file System.Linq.ni.pdb
Symbols failed to load for system.security.cryptography.dll. Failed to find local symbol file System.Security.Cryptography.ni.pdb
Symbols failed to load for system.text.regularexpressions.dll. Failed to find local symbol file System.Text.RegularExpressions.ni.pdb

Cause of problem
There is a bug in .NET 8 that (if I understand correctly) means that PDB files aren't being generated correctly for framework DLLs.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/96897 discusses the problem that I am having. Linked from there is https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/96917 which discusses the technical causes of the problem.
In the discussion thread at the first of these links, a project contributor has this to say:

This is [a] .NET 8 bug, tracked by #96917 and related issues. It will be fixed in [a] future servicing update.

However, there is no indication of when the promised update fixing this issue might arrive. The comment was made 3 months ago. As far as I can tell, I have the latest version of the .NET 8 SDK (version 8.0.202).
What I am looking for
I would like to know what workarounds exist for this problem, if any, that will allow me to accomplish my goal of seeing the information that would be displayed in the bottom pane of the "Call Tree" view if everything was working as intended.
